# Retrieve array from map function

Tags: javascript, arrays

i'm scraping an array of words, but i can't seem to get the a tags text into an array.

this is the html

```
<span class="entry-categories">
  Filed Under: 
  <a href="http://" rel="category tag">Review</a>, 
  <a href="http://" rel="category tag">News</a>, 
  <a href="http://" rel="category tag">Sport</a>, 
  <a href="http://" rel="category tag">Cars</a>
  <a href="http://" rel="category tag">Events</a>
  <a href="http://" rel="category tag">Constest</a>
  <a href="http://" rel="category tag">Casino</a>
 </span>
```

this html i'm retrieving by following code:

```
var keyWords = $('span.entry-categories a').map(function(index, element) {
    return $(this).text();
});
```

it is showing like this:

```
{ '0': 'Review',
  '1': 'News',
  '2': 'Sport',
  '3': 'Cars',
  '4': 'Events',
  '5': 'Constest',
  '6': 'Casino',
  options: 
   { withDomLvl1: true,
     normalizeWhitespace: false,
     xmlMode: false,
     decodeEntities: true },
  _root: 
   { '0': 
      { type: 'root',
        name: 'root',
        attribs: {},
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: null,
        parent: null },
     options: 
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xmlMode: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     length: 1,
     _root: [Circular] },
  length: 7,
  prevObject: 
   { '0': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'a',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     '1': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'a',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     '2': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'a',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     '3': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'a',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     '4': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'a',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     '5': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'a',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: [Object],
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     '6': 
      { type: 'tag',
        name: 'a',
        attribs: [Object],
        children: [Object],
        next: null,
        prev: [Object],
        parent: [Object] },
     options: 
      { withDomLvl1: true,
        normalizeWhitespace: false,
        xmlMode: false,
        decodeEntities: true },
     _root: { '0': [Object], options: [Object], length: 1, _root: [Circular] },
     length: 7,
     prevObject: { '0': [Object], options: [Object], length: 1, _root: [Circular] } } }
```

the desired result is something like this:

```
['Review', 'News', 'Sport', 'Cars', 'Events', 'Constest', 'Casino']
```

Comment: How are you getting that representation?

Comment: updated was missing something try look question again

Comment: Just read the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/map/) attentively: _As the return value is a jQuery object, which contains an array, it's very common to call .get() on the result to work with a basic array._

Comment: instead of get() use toArray() its way more readable :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you got is the jQuery object, but you wanted the array of elements. Use [`.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/):

```
var keyWords = $('span.entry-categories a').map(function(index, element) {
  return $(this).text();
}).get();
```